# PHP&Laravel: redirect and terminate script in whole (not only one function)

Tags: php, laravel

It's already exist many answers on questions like "How to terminate function executing in PHP", but in this question we consider the termination not only one function but also functions that will be called after first one.

Assume that it's not allowed to send feedback two or more times during one session. The method `abortRequestIfAnotherOneWithSameIdExistsInDatabase()` must to redirect user on top page and terminate not only itself, but also all methods that will be called after it in `submitConsultationRequest()`:

```
<?php

// Laravel Controller
class FeedbackController extends Controller {

    public function submitConsultationRequest(){

        $this -> abortRequestIfAnotherOneWithSameIdExistsInDatabase();
        // otherMethods ...
    }

    private function abortRequestIfAnotherOneWithSameIdExistsInDatabase(){

        $queryResult = DB::table('requests') ->
            where( 'visitId' => request() -> session() -> get('visitId'),
        ]) -> first();

        if (!is_null($queryResult)) {
            redirect() -> route('top');
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

- In current code, the `submitConsultationRequest()` will not be terminated.
- Same if we add `return` before `redirect() -> route('top');`.
- `abort(404);` will display the `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.` page, but I need to redirect to top page and display error message (I'll take care myself with error message, please help me with `submitConsultationRequest()` termination).

Comment: instead of `!is_null` use `!empty` and catch your else  part too

Comment: O'K, but must to understand, why. If there is no row with current `VisitID` in database, `null` will be returned.  If we catch `if(!is_null)` and add `return` there, all code after if-block will be ignored. Would you please to explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a bad idea to stop executing this way. This will make your code confusing. I think it will be easier:

```
public function submitConsultationRequest ()
{
    if ($this->isAnotherOneWithSameIdExistsInDatabase()) {
        return redirect()->route('top');
    }

    // otherMethods ...
}


private function isAnotherOneWithSameIdExistsInDatabase ()
{
    return DB::table('requests')
        ->where( 'visitId' => request()->session()->get('visitId'))
        ->first();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'am striving to clean code.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could do this?

```
<?php

// Laravel Controller
class FeedbackController extends Controller {

    public function submitConsultationRequest(){

        $result = $this -> abortRequestIfAnotherOneWithSameIdExistsInDatabase();

        if ($result instanceof \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse) {
            return $result;
        }

        // otherMethods ...
    }

    private function abortRequestIfAnotherOneWithSameIdExistsInDatabase(){
        $queryResult = DB::table('requests') ->
            where( 'visitId' => request() -> session() -> get('visitId'),
        ]) -> first();

        if (!is_null($queryResult)) {
            return redirect() -> route('top');
        }
    }
}
```

What this does is you return the `RedirectResponse` from your private function, and should your `submitConsultationRequest` catch it, return and terminate the codes below.

---

To me the code is a little bit stinky here, since your method `abortRequestIfAnotherOneWithSameIdExistsInDatabase` is doing two things at once. That's why the complication arised. You probably should make it drier by just doing one thing in one function:

```
class FeedbackController extends Controller
{
    public function submitConsultationRequest()
    {
        if (!$this->hasVisited()) {
            // Do the stuff when not visited
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('top');
        }
    }

    protected function hasVisited()
    {
        return DB::table('requests')
                 ->where('visitId' => request()->session()->get('visitId'))
                 ->exists();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution!

Comment: As you said the second solution is more cleaner, but it's required to rename methods. `submitConsultationRequest()` called from routes (web.php) but actually it just manage should we send the feedback or not. Code becomes dirtier if we will describe the logic inside `else{}`.  Also, If we catch `if (!$this->hasVisited())`, we must to submit the message, but we could not use `submitConsultationRequest` name again.

Comment: Hmm I thought it is almost no difference with the accepted answer? :) I'm a bit lost with your comment.

Comment: I am sorry, I can not accept two answers, so I can to please you just by gratitude.

Comment: No no, I did not, and absolutely not asking you to accept my answer. I am just curious, that what do you mean by your comment above, compare with what you say "it's clean" with your accepted answer, so I could clarify any doubts you have :)

Comment: You are right: your code and code in another answer is almost same.